# Return value for missing timestamp?

Tags: php

I have a simple cache-checking function which should return a timestamp. Is there a best practice for handling cases where there's nothing to return? This might happen if the cache hadn't been created yet or wasn't available for some reason.

Here's a simplified example:

```php
/**
 * @return int timestamp
 */
function getCacheTimestamp($cache)
{
    if ($cache) {
        return $cache->timestamp;
    } else
        return 0;  // what to return here? 0, -1, null, false ??
    }
}
```

Since the function is specified to return an integer/timestamp, it seems like `false` and `null` would be incorrect. But then, dealing with timestamps, `-1` isn't anymore false than `0`. Ultimately, whatever is returned really just needs to be 1 second older than the default expiration cutoff.

Comment: I'd return a false . . . there is no cache timestamp, so false seems like the appropriate response to me . . .

Comment: You could return a **false** and use === to do the comparison. I take it that `$cache->timestamp` is something created by `time()`? Is there a range of valid timestamps that you know your "missing" flag will never overlap?